# Chosen dropdown search is not working for dynamically populated options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using Chosen dropdown and populating the option dynamically. search in the dropdown is not working even i cant enter the text but it is working fine when dropdown options are static. Please help.

```
<select id="test" class="chosen-select"> 
    <option>Select1</option> 
</select> 

var div2=[]; 
div2.push("<option value='1'>ALL1</option>"); 
div2.push("<option value='2'>ALL2</option>"); 
div2.push("<option value='3'>ALL3</option>"); 
div2.push("<option value='4'>ALL4</option>"); 
div2.push("<option value='5'>ALL5</option>"); 
$("#test").html(div2.join('')); 

$("#test").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Comment: <select id="test" class="chosen-select">
                        <option>Select1</option>
                        
      </select>
        var div2=[];
        div2.push("<option value='1'>ALL1</option>");
        div2.push("<option value='2'>ALL2</option>");
        div2.push("<option value='3'>ALL3</option>");
        div2.push("<option value='4'>ALL4</option>");
        div2.push("<option value='5'>ALL5</option>");
        $("#test").html(div2.join(''));
        $("#test").trigger("chosen:updated");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to call `.chosen()` after you've dynamically populated the dropdown.

Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/npzs2bt7/

**EDIT 1 :**

Probably you didn't call `chosen()` on the dropdown before you could call `trigger("chosen:updated")`.

Updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/npzs2bt7/1/

**EDIT 2 :**

Using `Jquery 1.9.0`, `Chosen.Jquery 1.1.0`

Copy this into an html file (chosentest.html) and try it.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>chosen demo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.min.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            #test
            {
              width:100px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="test" class="chosen-select"> 
          <option>Select1</option> 
        </select>
        <button class="btn">Click to see selected value</button>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                //first call chosen()
                $("#test").chosen();

                 var div2=[]; 
                 div2.push("<option value='1'>ALL1</option>"); 
                 div2.push("<option value='2'>ALL2</option>"); 
                 div2.push("<option value='3'>ALL3</option>"); 
                 div2.push("<option value='4'>ALL4</option>"); 
                 div2.push("<option value='5'>ALL5</option>"); 
                 $("#test").html(div2.join('')); 

                 //this will bind the updates
                 $("#test").trigger("chosen:updated"); 

                 //text button to alert selected value from dropdown
                 $(".btn").click(function(){
                    alert($("#test").val());
                }); 
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here is my sample code
<select id="test" class="chosen-select">
                        <option>Select1</option>
                        
      </select>
        var div2=[];
        div2.push("<option value='1'>ALL1</option>");
        div2.push("<option value='2'>ALL2</option>");
        div2.push("<option value='3'>ALL3</option>");
        div2.push("<option value='4'>ALL4</option>");
        div2.push("<option value='5'>ALL5</option>");
        $("#test").html(div2.join(''));
        $("#test").trigger("chosen:updated");

Comment: Hey @Sridhar it works fine. Based on your comments, I've updated the fiddle.Check the updated answer.

Comment: Hi Prashanth, Thanks for your quick response. Still no luck....i am using Chosen v1.1.0...are you using same version? not sure it is due to version issue

Comment: Hi @Sridhar you must be missing something. Check 'Edit 2'. I'm loading jquery and chosen.jquery from CDN. It works well with v1.1.0

Comment: Hi Prashanth, it is working fine for me when i use chosen v1.5.1 but not working for chosen v1.1.0.....Thanks